# Joining two table and get data from both table based on certain column in django

Tags: python, django

At first i want to make understand you to be not overactive or over-reactive without giving any solution and not understanding the core content and topics of questions.Here many people available who are expert at overacting and over-reacting by giving minus vote knowing anything.If you do not like this question then ignore it because your minus vote prevent many important questions from getting researched and answered.

However, have two table named 'transaction' and 'member'. I want to join this two table like this :-

```
$select=$connect->query("SELECT transaction.id as id,transaction.date as date,member.name as name,member.address as address FROM transaction,member WHERE transaction.member_id=member.id ORDER  BY transaction.id ");
     while($data=$select->fetch_assoc()){

     echo $data['id'];
     echo $data['name'];
     //i echo it for your clearance 
     }
```

I need Django  query from it which i will get same result.

Please don't give any other questions reference something related to it.I need specific solution from  this.

Comment: Share you models

Comment: I have no models like this.i have only given example.you can answer based on this two imagination table and guessing two models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This select_related part will join the two tables (transaction, member) with condition (transaction.member_id=member.id ) then order_by('id') will order the output with transaction.id

```
query = transaction.objects.select_related('member').order_by('id')
```

To print ids

```
print(list(query.values_list('id', flat=True))))
```

To print list on names

```
print(list(query.values_list('names', flat=True))))
```

Comment: Ahmed Mansey@ if two tables has same field name then how to get specific table column data?